# Adjektiv für Punkt-zu-Punkt-Operationen

Tags: single-word-request

Es gibt Operationen, die Punkt-zu-Punkt- und solche, die Punkt-zu-Mehrpunkt-Kommunikation realisieren.

Für Punkt-zu-Mehrpunkt-Operationen habe ich das Adjektiv kollektiv gefunden, also kollektive Operationen sind Punkt-zu-Mehrpunkt-Operationen. Seht ihr das auch so, und habt sogar einen Alternativvorschlag?

Und gibt es auch ein Adjektiv für Punkt-zu-Punkt-Operationen?

Comment: Wie wäre es mit eins-zu-eins (1:1) bzw eins-zu-viele (1:n)? Ich kenne Dein Fachgebiet nicht, aber in Bezug auf Netzwerkkommunikation oder Datenbanken wäre das gebräuchlich.

Comment: Im Kommunikationbereich heißt das fachsprachlich meines Wissens "one to one" und "one to many"-Kommunikation. Ansonsten irgendwas mit individual / individuell, aber dazu bräuchten wir mehr Kontext.

Comment: Unter "kollektiv" würde ich sowohl "Punkt-zu-Mehrpunkt" als auch "Mehrpunkt-zu-Mehrpunkt" verstehen.

Comment: Es geht um das Message Passing Interface aus der Informatik. Die Broadcast Operation wäre zum Beispiel eine Punkt zu Mehrpunkt Operation.

Comment: Als das noch Elektrotechnik statt (Technische) Informatik war, gab es _Rundfunk_ (1:∞ ‘broadcast’ bzw. 1:n ‘multicast’), _Richtfunk_ (1:1 ‘unicast’) und – da bin ich mir nicht ganz sicher – _Funknetz_ (m:n bzw, m:∞). Gefunkt wird in diesem Fall aber wenig (mit tatsächlichen Funken schon gar nicht), während das engl. _cast_ auch in der digitalen Welt ganz gut funktioniert. Man könnte versuchen, _funk+_ durch _send+_ zu ersetzen, also _Rund-/Richtsendung_ und _Sendenetz_, aber das erscheint mir nicht gebräuchlich und auch nicht richtig intuitiv verständlich. (_+sand[t]_ ist leider auch raus.)

Comment: Um den richtigen Ausdruck zu finden müsste man auch wissen, ob bei Punkt-zu-Mehrpunkt-Operationen alle möglichen Empfänger erreicht werden oder nicht. Auf Englisch sagt man im ersten Fall _broadcast_, im zweiten [_multicast_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich habe leider keine klare Antwort auf die Frage, sondern kann nur mit Einschätzungen und Ideen dienen.

### *kollektiv* : *x*

*Kollektiv*, also gruppiert, sind Punkt-zu-Mehrpunkt-Operationen streng genommen nur dann, wenn es sich um eine Vielzahl gesammelter oder gebündelter Punkt-zu-Punkt-Operationen handelt, die gemeinsam ausgeführt werden. 
Das schließt echten **Rundfunk** (*broadcast*) aus, da das eine einzige Operation mit unbekannt vielen Empfängern ist. 
Beim eingeschränkten Rundfunk (*multicast*) ist höchstens die Anzahl der potentiellen Empfänger der nächstunteren Ebene bekannt, aber weder, welche das Signal tatsächlich erhalten, noch, in welchem Umfang sie es weiterleiten.

Am ehesten bilden *selektiv* und *singulär* sowie die bereits genannten *individuell* und *individual* **Antonyme** zu *kollektiv*. Auf Deutsch wäre das dann z.B. *vereinzelt* oder *Einzel-* oder *(aus)gewählt*. Wie gesagt, halte ich diese Begriffe hier aber nicht für angebracht.

### Alternativen

Bei 1:1 handelt es sich um Paare, die bei bidirektionaler Kommunikation sogar gleichberechtigt/-rangig/-wertig (*symmetrisch*), also beide evtl. abwechselnd sowohl Sender als auch Empfänger sein können. Das Adjektiv *paarig* fände ich daher nicht schlecht, je nach Enge der Verknüpfung auch *gepaart* oder *gekoppelt*. Mehrere 1:1-Operation laufen dann *paarweise* ab. Kopplung deutet an, dass auch Kettenoperationen möglich sind, könnte aber auch wie *kollektiv* verstanden werden.

Leider fehlt mir ein dazu passendes Adjektiv für 1:n. Häufig handelt es sich dabei um hierarchische, asymmetrische *Master:Slave*- oder *Server:Client*-Architekturen (je nach Hauptrichtung), die im Deutschen meist unübersetzt bleiben.

In der **Geometrie** gibt es neben Geraden ohne Start und Ziel einerseits die Strahlen mit festem Ausgangspunkt und andererseits die beidseitig begrenzten Strecken. Daraus ließen sich die Adjektive  *streckenförmig*, *streckenhaft* oder evtl. **streckig* (1:1) vs. *strahlenförmig*, *ausgestrahlt* und **strahlig* (1:n) ableiten.

Unter Umständen kann der entscheidende Unterschied zwischen 1:1 und 1:n aber auch durch *gerichtet* oder *beschränkt* vs. *ungerichtet* oder *frei* erfasst werden.

### Neubildungen

In der Informatik wird selten gefunkt (und auch in der Elektrotechnik fliegen dabei nur selten echte Funken), sondern **gesendet** (oder übertragen), daher könnte man versuchen, in den klassischen Begriffen *Rundfunk*, *Richtfunk* und *Funknetz* das *funk+* durch *send+* zu ersetzen, also *Rundsendung/Rundsenden, Richtsendung/Richtsenden* und *Sendenetz*, aber das erscheint mir nicht gebräuchlich und auch nicht richtig intuitiv verständlich.
(**Rundsand / *Richtsand* analog zu *Versand* ist leider raus, weil das Morphem auf diese Art schon lange nicht mehr produktiv ist und – wichtiger – mit *Sand* kollidiert.)

Relativ transparent, aber frisch selbstgeschöpft sind **einzielig* (1:1), **mehrzielig* (1:m, m>1), **vielzielig* (1:n, n>m) bzw. *gezielt* (1:p, 1 ≤ p < ∞) und **unzielig* (1:∞) bzw. *ungezielt*. Bei Bedarf kann man entsprechend auch **einquellig*, vielleicht auch **einhäuptig* (1:x) etc. bilden. Diese **Neologismen** beschreiben gefühlt eher unidirektionale Kommunikation als bidirektionale. 
Um (ein)gebildeter zu klingen, könnte man diese Wörter natürlich analog auch mit lateinischen oder griechischen Wurzeln bilden, z.B. *(mono- / multi-/pluri-/poly- / a-/non-)*destinativ*.

### Symbole und Metaphern

Es ist auch anderswo üblich, Buchstabenformen als symbolhafte Metaphern zu verwenden. Damit könnte man bspw. I-Operationen (1:1) von Y-, T-, V- oder A-Operationen (1:n) unterscheiden. (Psi Ψ ginge auch und M oder W stände für m:n bereit.) Für ein Adjektiv böte sich eine Zusammensetzung mit *-artig* oder *-förmig* an.

Answer (score 1):

Ohne aus dem Fachgebiet zu sein, in dem diese Termini verwendet werden, schlage ich neben den Vorschlägen aus den Kommentaren (Eins-zu-Eins-, Eins-zu-N (1:1, 1:N)) **lineare**, vielleicht besser **direkte**, und **sternförmige** Kommunikation vor. 
Eine Punkt-zu-Punkt-Kommunikation mit Rückkanal könnte man auch **dialogartig** nennen.

Comment: Hmm, bei _sternförmig_ würde ich mitgehen. _Linear_ in Bezug auf Kommunikation würde ich nicht mit den Multiplizitäten, sondern eher mit der Komplexität (Zeitaufwand z. B.) assoziieren und nicht verstehen.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Ist 'direkte' besser?

Comment: Ja, etwas. Aber hier würde ich dann schon wieder an vermittelte Kommunikation denken, also z. B. über einen Proxy - bzw. eben an das Gegenteil dessen. 'Tschuldigung :(

Comment: Eine Sternstruktur impliziert i.d.R., dass sich die Clients an den Strahlenden über den Server im Zentrum miteinander unterhalten können – sofern nicht eindeutig geklärt ist, dass es sich um unidirektionale (Push-)Kommunikation handelt.

Comment: @Crissov: Eine Kommunikationsstruktur wie ein Fernsehsender, der an viele Empfänger sendet, würde ich auch als Sternstruktur bezeichnen. In meinem Blog dagegen gibt es einen Rückkanal von den Lesern zu mir (Kommentare).

Comment: @userunknown: Und wo läuft der Rückkanal entlang, wenn nicht genau entgegengesetzt und somit deckungsgleich zu einem der Sternstrahlen - sprich, ohne etwas an der Sternstruktur zu ändern?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ehm - verstehe jetzt nicht ganz, was die Frage ist. 2 Personen die direkt miteinander verbunden sind, auf der einen Seite. Auf der anderen eine Sternstruktur, bei der entweder die Personen über einen Proxy verbunden sind, das Zentrum des Sterns. Ein Stern kann aber auch einen Fernsehsender darstellen mit einem Sender in der Mitte und vielen Empfängern, die aber untereinander nicht verbunden sind, auch nicht über den Fernsehsender. Die Beschreibung als Stern sagt nichts darüber aus, ob es einen Rückkanal gibt. Punkt-zu-Mehrpunkt-Kommunikation schließt einen Rückkanal aus?

Comment: @userunknown: Ah, ich glaube, ich verstehe die Verwirrung. Ich (und vermutlich auch Crissov) sehe den Blog als das Zentrum des Sterns, und die Spitzen des Sterns als die Nutzer, die entweder nur im Blog lesen, oder auch Kommentare im Blog hinterlassen. Alle Nutzer können auf die Kommentare zugreifen, weil diese von den Schreibern ja auch ins Zentrum wandern.